# Use signalR websockets to listen to a non signalR server?

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

I have a websocket connection where I want to constantly listen and receive events on that websocket's URL. It's a status watcher, and I will be returned a json on a regular basis. I have a signalR client that is listening to a server/hub on one point. There is also a third device, not the signalR server or the battery, that has a websocket connection.

Is it possible to setup a SignalR client, point it to a websocket server that is not signalR, and just listen to all the traffic that way? I have a listener already in the SignalR client built in, could I make a "second hub" and have it listen also to the other websocket on the other device? It's not one I have control over, and is not a SignalR server, but since it's a websocket connection, shouldn't I be able to read off of it?

Here is a high tech diagram to help.

[image]

Comment: SignalR client only works for SignalR server. If you have a generic WebSocket server to connect, use a WebSocket client directly.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to see if there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR client cannot connect to any websocket. First, websocket is just one transport that SignalR uses but not the only one. If the client cannot connect to the server it will by default automatically switch to a different transport (e.g. server sent events or long polling). Second, SignalR uses a protocol to talk to the server (if you are interested you can find the protocol description [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/)) - if the protocol is not followed the client won't be able to connect to the server. Hence the SignalR client can only work with a SignalR server.